# Preview quarantine madness: it quarantines files as I'm editing them

Tags: permission, preview, extended-attributes

Preview seems to set the quarantine on files that it opens.  Kind of, unpredictably.  And, it could be, that quarantine is set randomly through other mechanisms; not sure.  Let me illustrate.

I have several big directories of jpeg files.  So, I'm going through, cropping several files at once in Preview.  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> crop, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> save, down arrow on to the next file, dozens, usually no problems.  Then I get to this one file, and, upon Save, it says 'The document "xxx.jpg" could not be saved.'  Sometimes I go to the terminal and do an `ls -l@O` on the file, but I know what it's going to say:  No `rwx` permission problems, no `-O` settings, just a quarantine.

Sometimes, I try clearing the quarantine while open in Preview, but that never works, still cannot be saved.  I tried closing it, discarding changes, but I don't have permission to do that, either.  I try doing a Duplicate, but I don't have permission for that either.  In fact, I can't even close the file, because the only two options are to save or discard, and I don't have permissions to do either.  The only way out is to either crash Preview or to quit, where it gives me an option to Duplicate.  I click the button; maybe a duplicate is created. but it quits and I never see it.

I can go through this routine over and over.  I get rid of all quarantines.  Open the file in Preview.  Instantly, a quarantine is set on the file, along with another attribute, can't remember.  Delete all those xattrs, ls says no more quarantine.  Click on the Preview window to bring it to the front; then click back to terminal; the quarantine on the file is set again.  None of the other files I've been cropping for the last half hour have their quarantines set, nor had any problems saving.  None of the Unix permission bits seem to have any involvement, nor the Finder's Get Info permissions; everything is Read & Write for everybody.

Regularly, I do an `xattr -c * .` to get rid of all the quarantines that come out of nowhere.  But, new files come in, from directories that I similarly remove quarantines from.  Maybe their quarantines are set from downloading or bitrot or whatever.  I actually clear xattrs in a cron job because the problem is so bad; that helps a lot.  All of the files do, ultimately, come from download, but their xattrs are cleared, permissions set to 666, renamed, some converted from pngs, etc.

My OS right now is '14.2.1 (23C71)', but it's been going on for years, since at least OS X.14, **on my previous Mac**.  There is no quarantine set on any file in `/System/Applications/Preview.app`.

Does anybody else have this problem?  Does anybody have a clue as to what's going on?

Primer on Quarantine: All Mac files have 'extended attributes', little additional chunks of data, often text.  Key-value like `com.apple.quarantine` sets a quarantine on the file.  If you do `ls -l`, an `@` shows if a file has extended attributes.  An `ls -l@` will list their keys and lengths.  An `xattr -l` will list their values.  The value of the quarantine attr says what app did it.  An `xattr -c` deletes all of them on a file.

Comment: Have you tried moving aside the com.apple.Preview container from your home directory? Other odd issues with Preview have been resolved that way.

Comment: What is the filepath of the files' location?

Comment: ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview